# twig - get an IF statement out of a loop

Tags: php, for-loop, if-statement, twig

I have the following problem. I have a FOR loop and couple of IF statements like this:

```
{% for option in group %}
 {% if option.type == 'palette' %}
   {% for option_value in option.product_option_value %}
     {% if option_value.image %}
     <div>I am here</div>
     {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I just want to check/create one IF statements showing whether or not there is **option_value.image**
anywhere (showing at least once).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a variable to 0 and set it to 1 inside the if statement then you can check if 1 or 0

Comment: Thanks, that worked!

Comment: But I still think there should be a shorter way of doing it

Comment: No there is not, you can't break out of a loop inside `twig`. You would need to add a custom `function` / `filter` to achieve a "shorter" solution.

Comment: Is there a way I can break out of the loop after the first result is hit?

Comment: Read my previous comment?